# Dimension of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider two subspaces V and W of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
dim(V) + dim(W) = dim(V ∩ W) + dim(V + W).

Can anyone provide me with the proof for this?

Comment: Can? Yes. Will? No.

Comment: Think of a  map from $V \times W \to \mathbb{R}^n$, whose kernel is $V \cap W$ and image is $V+W$.